# Apache + Passenger + Rails 3.2.5 - Production Server / Javascript wont work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, assets, passenger

Dear StackOverflow Community,

Since i started to deploy my rails APP on a Apache + Passenger Server i got problems.
But the last one, i couldnt find a solution, hope you guys can help me. :)

My application is running, but Javascript wont work on Production mode, only on development mode.
When i deploy, the app runs, but my ajax menus and other JS functions dont work.
I inspected with Firebug, it loads a big application.js with all javascript, and everything looks OK, but JS just dont work.

Someone can help?

Follows my Production.rb:

```
SIGMA::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in
config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  #config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = false

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use
Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

 # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and
all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

As i said in begin, in development mode everything runs OK, only stop works @ production mode.

Thanks for any Help!

Comment: did you run bundle exec rake assets:precompile
on the production box?

Comment: Yes! not only precompile as clean and tmp:clear too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Solved after uncomment following line:

## config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache

of my Production.rb and declaring all javascripts on my assets/javascript folder on:
config.assets.precompile